# Does t-SNE in 3 dimensions offer any additional information to 2 dimensional t-SNE?

Tags: data-visualization, tsne

t-SNE is a data reduction technique that primarily gives information about local similarities. Clustering in a t-SNE graph usually ([but not always)](https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) indicates some hidden structure in the higher-dimensional data.

While there are some shapes and features in 3d space that cannot be translated onto a 2d space (things like chirality and knots), how usual, practically speaking, is it to come across real life data (including things like word-vectors and neural network weights of image-classifiers) that only reveals structure/intelligible features in three dimensions and not two?

Comment: Just try it in 3D to see if there’s a gain in insight.

Comment: t-SNE is a very computationally hungry algorithm (O(n^2)) and I am already doing it on only a small subset (15,000 out of 1,600,000 rows) of the data. I am currently preparing both 2d and 3d visualisations but it takes ages each time. So far, I'm not getting much out of the 3d visualisation, but I'm not getting too much meaningful info out of the 2d one either.

Comment: Re speed: why are you using exact tSNE? Since around 5 years, it is standard to use Barnes-Hut t-SNE which is O(n*log(n)) and can easily process ~100k rows. Since last year I recommend everybody to use FI t-SNE which is O(n) and can embed 1 mln points in <30 min.

Comment: Go big and go to UMAP. :)

Comment: I've read about UMAP and it's on my list of things to try. I'll have a look at Barnes- Hut too